# JAX-WS Ruby client

Tags: ruby, client, jax-ws

I knew Ruby community favors REST style, but I need to access a JAX-WS document style web service.

SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(SERVICE_WSDL).create_rpc_driver

doesn't work for document style.

I looked at Handsoap and Savon. They seems to manipulate the low level soap message. Is there a gem which can do similarly as RPC driver. Just load WSDL, and use the interface directly.

Comment: what do you mean by 'use the interface directly'? savon is just sending plain http requests. what's wrong with that?